# Compute Visual Profiler giving error when opening

Tags: cuda, nvidia

after installing Compute Visual Profiler,

I open it with this error:

> Unable to load the 'nvcuda' library.
>
> Computer Visual Profiler device features will be disabled.

My computer does not have NVIDIA graphic card. Would it be a problem causing this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Profiler is designed to execute programs and collect profile data, it's looking for the NVIDIA driver and when it can't find the driver it tells you. You should still be able to use the Visual Profiler to load projects created on other machines with CUDA capable GPUs.

Comment: At a server, I produced a profiler output with a command like "nvprof -o profile.out ./myprog". Then I tried to open this output using Visual Profiler on my laptop, which has no NVIDIA graphics card. Because the driver is not installed, it gives error whiling trying to open this file :(

Comment: @phoad: that's correct I'm afraid, currently you do need to have the driver installed to load the profile. Have you considered using NX to connect to the server and hence run nvvp remotely? Of course that relies on you have or being able to install NX on the remote machine, but I've had good experience doing that (e.g. on Amazon's AWS GPU nodes).